# Which methods and class will Safari call when it's launched?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reverse-engineering

I want to class-dump methods and class of safari launching for get the DOM OBJECT in the webpage. But I didn't know which methods and class will be called when it launch ? Thank you very much !

Comment: You can stop posting this same question over and over any time now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, what? WebKit, Safari's rendering engine, is open-source. Just grab a copy of the source from [webkit.org](http://webkit.org/building/checkout.html).

Comment: Yes, I know the WebKit is the rendering enginne. but I want to know which method or class the safari will call when it launched? Because I will overwrite that method in my plugin class when class-dump webkit.